# Difference between eclipse macosc cocoa 64bit vs just mac64 bit.dmg installer

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, download

So i came across 2 download links for eclipse

- One that is just the regular eclipse inst for mac 64 bit https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
- The other is a Mac cocoa 64 bit installer https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

The first one **doesn't work** after downloading onto the mac. It will prompt an error that says you need to install legacy Java SE6 runtime ?

What does that all mean? can someone give me a brief breakdown?

Thank you!!